# Ethical obligation after finding fraudulent applicant?

Tags: resume, ethics, hiring, fraud

Acme Co. screens and places candidates at other companies including those fictionally-named Bravo and Tec2.

Candidate J. Doe applies for a role with Bravo, including a resume citing a lot of experience on a project at Tec2.

Acme learns that this is a serious misrepresentation, through a combination of its own knowledge resulting from the partnership with Tec2 and J. Doe's performance on interview questions that should have been easy if the resume was truthful.

Beyond simply declining to hire the candidate, does Acme have any further ethical responsibilities?

Comment: So you say J. Doe actually lied on his resume? What Acme decides to do is really up to them and how that  company handles this situations.

Comment: Ethical responsibilities to whom?

Comment: @ DarkCygnus Yes, J. Doe lied on the resume, and not just a typo or innocent mistake. @Paparazzi Anybody, including but not limited to the applicant and/or other prospective employers who may not be as well positioned to quickly identify the misrepresentation.

Comment: You might want to check with your lawyer before you decide to warn prospective employers.

Comment: Not clear how "J. Doe's performance on interview questions that should have been easy if the resume was truthful" proves that J Doe did not work at Tec2.  Could have worked there and just never learned the business.

Comment: The close reason does not apply to this question.  I'm not asking a question about the specific policies of any one company which should be directed to that company's HR department.  I'm also not asking about legal obligations, but more about ethics & professionalism.  I think the question is on-topic for this site but appear to be in the minority with that view.

Comment: @cdkMoose It can be pretty clear.  As an example, imagine an applicant saying they were responsible for managing all of a company's many real estate purchases/sales/deals and then being unable to come up with the name or address of a single property they worked with.

Comment: @cdkMoose or a developer who claims to have personally done the code-writing implementation for some publicly accessible web application, and can describe what the application does, but doesn't know what programming language it's written in.  Those kinds of questions should be easy.

Comment: VOTED TO REOPEN:  Reasons here:  https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4895/req-to-reopen-this-question

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this a question of business policy not about navigating the work place

Comment: I would vote to close, if it weren't for the bounty preventing me. This is entirely opinion based, as are many ethical questions.

Comment: @RoryAlsop This site has many questions about standards of professionalism and ethics (see Related --> for examples), and best practices may have been developed for responding to this situation as it's nowhere near novel.  A question on this site isn't valid question if it seeks a clear-cut legal or workplace-specific answer; nor is it valid if it's fuzzier than that where different people might have different answers. If all these exclusions really should be upheld, why don't we just give up and close the site?

Comment: Given the number of existing close votes and the multiple requests to revoke the bounty to allow a final close vote I've revoked your bounty @TheSnarkKnight. This question is obviously in a gray area so to everyone involved: please try to arrive at a compromise in chat or on the meta thread. Remember that it's fine for your personal opinion of a question's usefulness to differ from that of the community but if a significant number of people think the question has value consider simply stepping back and leaving them to it.

Answer (score 16):

Literally any employer could find this out by

- contacting Tec2 to verify references (even start and end date, which is all some companies do, would presumably expose the lies)
- asking the same sort of questions you asked in the interview

You don't appear to have needed or relied on your relationship with Tec2 to discover this person is a fraud. Any company out there that does even minimal screening would make the same discovery. And any that doesn't (sure, they exist) would not be hooked into whatever mechanism or  backchannel you're thinking of using to spread the word about an exaggerated, inflated, or even entirely fictional resume.

People do this. That's why interviewers check. And interviewers who check don't hire people who do this. You don't have a part to play in this beyond protecting your own agency from hiring or placing this person, which you did.

Answer (score 4):

> Beyond simply declining to hire the candidate, does Acme have any
>   further ethical responsibilities?

Besides not placing the candidate, I don't think there is anything further for you to do from an ethical or just plain ole professional point of view.  You definitely **can not spread the word**, so to speak, about J. Doe being a bad candidate.

Something you **could** do is share the feedback you received with J. Doe in an attempt to help them grow or perhaps refine their resume.

Comment: I'd only speak to the candidate if there's a chance of a misunderstanding or jumping to conclusions. If they feel the need to falsify their experience, I'd argue that they're not the best person to be trying to help.

Comment: *"You definitely can not spread the word"* - why not? That seems like a reasonable and civic-minded thing to do, to me. (Assuming you can prove the lie, of course - otherwise you're creating a legal risk.)

Answer (score 4):

I would say: it depends.

In general, you wouldn't hunt people with misrepresentation on their resume. That could even bounce back to you. And cost a lot of money in litigation.

However, if for instance the fraud is that someone claims he's a doctor and you find out that he isn't. And you later find out he's working somewhere else as a doctor. I would inform that company.

So my answer is: 90% of the times, just let it go, but there are situations where you actually have to. It depends on the actual fraud.

Answer (score 2):

> Beyond simply declining to hire the candidate, does Acme have any further ethical responsibilities?

None at all including hiring the chap despite the dodginess. Businesses do not have clear cut ethical responsibilities. They have legal obligations.

Comment: This question and most others on this site would not exist if legal obligations were all that mattered.

Comment: @WBT as far as business goes, they are all that matters. If the OP has asked on behalf of a person that would be different. But as a business ethics have no real part, and indeed legalities are just obstacles to accruing profit.

Comment: If the strict compliance with the law and only that are all that matter in the workplace, this site should be shut down and all relevant questions moved over to Law.SE.  Alternatively, continue browsing and you might find some questions about professionalism and ethics that go beyond the law's requirements, even questions you yourself have asked.  E.g. "[Is there a good ratio of HR to staff?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/64036/is-there-a-good-ratio-of-hr-to-staff)" According to legal obligations, it's probably 0 or 1 per 100% of staff. Is that the kind of answer you'd like?

Comment: @WBT I have no idea what you're on about, I'm talking about business not workplace. Obviously it's a subset rather than the whole thing.

Comment: If businesses do not have ethical responsibilities, people should have no ethical responsibilities to the business. We do have ethical responsibilities to each other,  but not to a business. However, this "lie" is nothing personal, and entirely to the company. Thus, the chap did nothing unethical by lying on his resume.

Comment: @DanielGrover in my society lying is unethical and frowned upon regardless of who you are lying to. Still happens though.

Comment: Daniel Grover's answer is very much aligned with the core of yours: "Legal obligations are all that matter."

Answer (score -1):

From a **professional** perspective, doing anything more than weeding out the candidate of your own recruitment process would be unethical.

Reason is simple: The purpose of any for-profit company is to maximize its (financial) success. It is unethical to abuse it´s resources for other goals.

Volunteering Information to third parties takes your and their resources, and does not serve this goal from your perspective. Apart from that, it is possibly opening you up to all sorts of legal and data-protection issues the could pose a risk to your organisation.

*You are offering to volunteer a service nobody ordered and nobody pays for!*

Note: This answer would be different, if you where, for example, part of a network of entrepreneurs who mutually join forces to screen for bad candidates.